# get earliest date from array of objects with dates

Tags: javascript

I have a list of dates saved from a `<input id="datepicker" type="datetime-local">` element. The format I get from the input element is like `2020-03-27T23:39:12`.

My array is similar to:

```
[
    {id:"asda2", date: "2020-03-27T23:39:12"},
    {id:"lj231", date: "2020-03-27T22:45:02"},
    {id:"pqeng", date: "2020-03-27T21:58:15"}
]
```

I want to sort the array objects by date, and get the earliest date.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Since your dates are in ISO-8601 format, you can sort them directly as strings.

Comment: Thanks Nick, the similar question solved my issue.